# What is a good way to store strings in Python?

Tags: python, json, string, csv, text

I am building a conversation bot in Python. While I would like to generate as much text as possible from scratch, I still need a way to catalog and store a bunch of dialog fragment strings. Ideally I would like to contain some sort of hierarchy/classifications among the strings.
For example:

Greetings:

`"Oh, nice to meet you {0}"
    "My name is Bob, how about you?"`

Flirtation:

`"Stop it"
    "I'm blushing"
    "How flattering"`

etc...

While I could store these in a database, it would be nice to have different format that people could edit easily by hand. CSV? JSON? Is there any precedent for stuff like this?

Comment: If you need to interact with users, JSON could be one of the best options!

Comment: What are your requirements for data persistence beyond the format being human-readable or easily editable? Answering that might narrow down the choice.

Comment: Probably the best format editable by a human is: raw text, one line per string.

Comment: CSV could work, but depending on the bot logic a database may be easier to work with. What other data are you storing besides the strings themselves?

Comment: I would agree with Andrea, unless you have multiline strings, in which case JSON is probably a better way to go.

Comment: I would like it to update on reboot according to changes in the data-format we are discussing. Potentially I could have a json file (that writers could edit), a json validation script, and a database ( or maybe just an object ) that would be updated accordingly and referenced in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends on how do you want to use it. If the strings are only meant to be used by Python you should consider storing them in their very own `.py` file. Yes, a module, but it is also a simple text file which happens that can be interpreted by Python :)

A lot of projects use `.py` files as configuration files (Django) and importing its contents is very easy since you only have to do `import answer_strings` and you'll already got them in variables or classes.

You can for example do this:

```
#bot answers module

greetings = ["hello {0}", "what's up {0}"]
farewells = ["see you soon {0}", "nos vemos {0}"]
...
```

And can return equivalent answers randomly, etc.

On the other side, if these are meant to be also read by Javascript, Java, node.js or whatever technology other than Python then a more universal format should be use, JSON, XML, YAML, you name it.

I think this is better in a text file (a project's resource) than in a database since that way (as you mentioned it) is more customizable. And I would also recommend to use a format that have *semantics* included. A CSV file is IMHO *very cold*, just a bunch of data dumped to a file. With XML, JSON, etc you can group your data in categories like "Greetings", "Farewells", etc, etc.

Not to forget that since you have several options, it would be very good to build your code in a modular way and decoupled. Thus, if you made a decision and in the future need to change, it would be as seamless as possible to accomplish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Python file that has power to execute anything shouldn't be used as a default storage format for simple lists of strings. json with preprocessed comments should be good enough. And OP can change the storage format or support several formats later.

Comment: I see, using json or xml is also more decoupled but since I have had good experience using `.py` as configurations files I felt it could be a valid choice. The point of my answer is to actually encourage the OP to use some text based file and not a database which might be overkill (IMHO) :) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The point is: All other things being equal, use the least powerful format that covers your current use case. If you need a *Turing-complete* configuration/markup language then Python is not a bad choice.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much information you want to store with the strings.

I think that for a simple case when the "database" is just list of strings, you could go with plain text, one string per line.  Advantage could be that such plain text files are easy to search/edit/manipulate with plethora of tools from GNU coreutils (like grep, sed...) to GUI editors.

This can be also easily extended by using using pre-defined file naming and directory hierarchy.  For example, structure like

```
data/
data/en_GB/greetings
data/en_GB/farewells
data/en_US/greetings
data/en_US/farewells
data/de_DE/greetings
data/de_DE/farewells
```

could allow you to pick your data by language, and even deploy only relevant languages on some systems.

If only your problem with this would be the newlines, you could still get away by the above plus using some kind of vertical separator like `~~~~`.

---

However, if you plan slightly more complicated structures and/or you expect them to change, a full serialization/markup language could make a lot of sense.  One of my favorite is [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), which is rich, mature, has libraries present for major languages language-agnostic and easily understood and edited by humans (look at their site: it's in YAML!).

```
# you can have comments for editors in YAML

# informal greetings are allowed
greetings:
    - "hello {0}"
    - "what's up {0}"

# bye, etc.
farewells:
    - "see you soon {0}"
    - "nos vemos {0}"

# please be polite here
flirtation:
    - "Stop it"
    - "I'm blushing"
    - "How flattering"
```

Comment: If you need translations then there is [GNU `gettext`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Why) that defines how the text could be stored